# How do I load a nested web page in a <div> tag using only javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a home page with multiple `<div>` tags. One of the `<div id="top_bar">` contains a link. If I click on the link, a new web page should load on one of the other `<div id="content">` in home page. How do I do that?

More over, if the newly loaded page on one of the other `<div id="content">` contains a link, and clicking on the link helps the 2nd new web page load in the `<div id ="content">` tag replacing the first content of the div , the question is how do I do that?

This is an assignment given to me and the rules are:

1. I have to use Javascript, CSS and HTML only.
2. I can't use `<iframe>` tag.
3. I can't use `<table>` tag either to load page in a row/column.

I need help and advice about how to do it.

home.html

```
  <body>
  <div id="topBar">
     <a href ="#" onclick="load_home()"> HOME </a>
     <a href="#"  onclick="load_about()"  > ABOUT </a> 
     <a href="#"  onclick="load_search()"> SONG LIST </a> 
  </div>
  <div id ="content"> </div>
  </body>
```

I want the music.html to open in side the < div id="content" > which all ready does. but in music.html there is a button. I want to open Songlist.html in < div id="content" > by clicking on that button. code for
music.html :

```
  <body >   
  <form name="flyrics" method="get" > 
         Lyrics: <input type ="text" name ="lyrics"/>   
         Artist Name:<input type ="text" name ="artist"  /> 
         <input type="submit" id="x" value="Search" /> 
  </form>
  </body>
```

javascript:

```
function load_home(){ document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="home.html"  id="link_pages" ></object>'; }
function load_about(){ document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="about.html"  id="link_pages" ></object>'; }
function load_search(){ document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="music.html"  id="link_pages" ></object>'; }
function validation(){
    var x=document.forms["flyrics"]["lyrics"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("Search without Lyrics?");
        return false;
    }

    var y=document.forms["flyrics"]["artist"] value;
    if (y==null || y=="")
    {
        alert("Search without Artist Name?");
        return false;
    }
    window.open("songList.html", "currentWindow");

}
```

Comment: Rule #3 seems weird, but an important question to have an answer to before you embark on a solution is if the two pages are on the same domain?

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried. "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed." http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: rule #3 is used for creating the home page with css layout only . no table is allowed to create/design the home page. And yes the all the pages in the same domain or I say in the same folder. @JasonSperske

Comment: I only say it looks weird because it is unrelated to the task of fetching HTML and modifying the DOM.  As long as the two pages are on the same domain you are free to do an Ajax fetch, and modify your document.  This complex code is actually wrapped in a super simple function in jQuery called [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).  However @showdev is right, you are going to have to demonstrate more effort before people will do the work for you.

Comment: Are you loading content from external HTML files? Or can all of the content exist in the same file?

Comment: all the contents are in the same folder. no external files are used. @showdev

Comment: I wish I could show you my code. problem is it is a part of a huge assignment. I'm puzzled to show all the code parts. its difficult to show the code for this part only since all the code parts are connected to each other. Still let me see what I can do to show code for this part only. @showdev

Comment: I edited a short version of my assignment with the question. don't get confused to see such big code. help how to solve it. @showdev

Comment: I finally found the solution of my problem. all I need is to use the formaction="url" attribute in the <input> tag. this solves the problem easily. :)

Comment: That solution doesn't match your requirements. You asked to load a page inside a div, not to load a new page with the data in the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one of your comments, you mentioned using `<object>` tags to embed external HTML files.

Here is an example using that method:

HTML:

```html
<div id="links">
  <a href="http://stuff.com" onclick="return go(this);">stuff</a>
  <a href="http://www.fun.com" onclick="return go(this);">fun</a>
  <a href="http://bing.com" onclick="return go(this);">bing</a>
</div>

<div id="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
div#container {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

JS:

```js
function go(obj) {
    var page=obj.href;
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML='<object data="'+page+
      '" type="text/html"><embed src="'+page+'" type="text/html" /></object>';
    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sAcCV/

**EDIT:**

This being said, I recommend using AJAX to load external content, instead:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxincludes.shtml

See [Relfor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456740/how-do-i-load-a-nested-web-page-in-a-div-tag-using-javascript-and-html-only/#17456809).

Comment: yes. it works. but what if obj.href has a link to another web page and I want to open it in <div id="container"> by clicking on the link and replacing current obj.href url. How do you do that? This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: I don't understand. Upon clicking a link, the code above takes the `href` from the `<a>` tags and embeds that URL in the `<div id="container">`. Are you referring to a link on the embedded page? I recommend using AJAX -- see [Relfor's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456740/how-do-i-load-a-nested-web-page-in-a-div-tag-using-javascript-and-html-only/#17456809).

Answer (score 4):

AJAX is what your assignment is looking for.

**Simple Example**

HTML:

```
<button id="nav">load</button>
<div id="page"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('nav').onclick = function(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xhr.readyState==4)
    {
        document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = xhr.response;

    }
  }
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.codecademy.com/", false);

xhr.send(); 
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DZmBG/3/

Comment: I hope you saw the rules. @Relfor

Comment: +1 best method. However @Giliweed, if you haven't learned AJAX in class, your teacher may be expecting something else. (In my experience, homework assignments are generally based on techniques learned in class.)

Comment: well, the truth is this assignment is for mid term examination only and Ajax is not included in mid term examination syllabus. when I pass mid term examination I will go for final term examination. and ajax , jqury are all in final term examination syllabus. So even if ajax gives an easy solution I'm not allowed to use it. sigh. I hope you understand why I'm trying to solve the problem in the hard way. @showdev

Answer (score 0):

Iframe is the obvious answer.  That's what it was made for.  But since your requirements state you can't use it....

Any site that's not within your domain is going to violate the same origin policy, and Javascript in the remote page is not going to run as you probably would think it would inside a div on your site.  You'd probably have to examine a CURL get approach or something similar to do it with a straight div and javascript.

Comment: cross origin issues can be solved with jsonp, and besides it seems that the webpage the OP wants to load is from within the same server.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is definitely the way to go if you are not able to use iframes. I would suggest using jQuery for this example to save some time. Their AJAX handling is pretty straightforward and you are gonna want to use their .live() or .on() event handlers to track the click events inside the containers.

Additionally, you may run into issues if you are loading sites on different domains. AJAX calls are typically meant for same-domain responses. You can get around this using JSONP. However, your web service must support method injection for this to work. In not, you may want to see if you can work around the iframe barrier with your host/webmaster.

Answer (score -3):

You can not. You are asking for something that can not be done. For such situation you must use iframe.

Comment: no. it is 50% possible using this code                                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="music.html"  id="link_pages" ></object>';       inside the <div id="content"> tag. but I don't know how to do the rest of the part. So It does work without using <iframe>.